# argument list for class template "std::iterator" is missing

Tags: c++, iterator, sfml

`argument list for class template "std::iterator" is missing`

I get this error with this occasion:

```
for(std::iterator it = deque.begin(); it != deque.end(); it++)
```

So i had an idea of specifying in template manner like this:

```
for(std::iterator<sf::RectangleShape> it = deque.begin(); it != deque.end(); it++)
```

But then i get different error:

`expected a declaration`

I am kind of confusing on what is going here. All i need is the iterator because that way i can get to the last element of `std::deque` and set it to a different rectangle color.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you following a guide that suggested using `std::iterator` like this?

Comment: C++ is complicated, you should read some learning material (preferably a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)). Just having ideas and then getting confused when they don't work is not going to get you very far. A book will teach you the principles behind the language.

Comment: I agree C++ is complicated, but i am trying to learn with what i can get online. Getting a book however, is what i just might do in near future. @john

Comment: All i found on encppreference, if that is what you mean by "guide", is that i can declare it like this ```std::iterator iteratorName``` Any example code is declared differently not as i want it. I know for example that with strings there is `std::string::iterator` and that makes thing easier *EDIT* as i see in the other answers, something similar to that is the case with what i am trying to accomplish too...

Comment: @logoslavikus I'd like to know on cppreference where it said you can declare `std::iterator iteratorName` because that is not correct. cppreference is normally very reliable (although not really aimed at beginners).

Comment: I just checked my history trough out whole day yesterday and i made a mistake. It seems i permuted something and i couldn't find any source from where i read it which basically means i might as well made it up. Sincerely sorry, i should think twice before making these blunt statements .

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to iterate through a `std::deque<sf::RectangleShape>`: The type returned by the non-`const` member functions `begin()` and `end()` of a `std::deque<sf::RectangleShape>` container is neither `std::iterator` nor `std::iterator<sf::RectangleShape>` but actually **`std::deque<sf::RectangleShape>::iterator`**:

```
for (std::deque<sf::RectangleShape>::iterator it = deque.begin(); it != deque.end(); ++it)
```

As already suggested in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63329685/8012646), you can, since C++11, simply rely on `auto`:

```
for (auto it = deque.begin(); it != deque.end(); ++it)
```

Having to write just `auto` instead of `std::deque<sf::RectangleShape>::iterator` is probably less prone to errors, as you may have already noticed. Even better, as you are iterating over the whole container, you can, since C++11, just use a [range-for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead:

```
for (auto& elem: deque)
```

In this case, `elem` is not an iterator to an element of `deque` but a reference to the element itself (i.e., `sf::RectangleShape&`).

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare the iterator with `auto`:

```
for (auto it = deque.begin(); it != deque.end(); it++)
```

to let the compiler decide the appropriate type for it.